# Jquery sortable, how to disable drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

```
<ul id="box">
<li id="1">1</li>
<li id="2">2</li>
</ul>



$("#box").sortable({ update: function() {
    var order = $("#box").sortable("serialize");
    alert(order);
  }
});
```

I would like to control the order by pressing buttons, and disable the drag and drop.
Everything works great but i could not figure out how to disable the drag and drop but still remain this list sortable?

Edit -

Ok now i start to understand this. I do not need to use sortable at all.
How to get the same result in order variable without using sortable?

Comment: How do you think to sort your items without using drag and drop ?

Answer (score 1):

On that case, you don't need sortable at all. Just use `.append()` and `.prepend()` to shift the position.

```
$("#link-left").click(function() {
   $("#placetoshift").append($("#thesortablediv"));
});
```

Comment: The only reason for sortable is i was not able to get the order of elements. I use li.insertBefore(li.prev()) as button commands for reorder. How can i get the exact order result as i get using sortable("serialize")?